# excel vba code to copy tabs to a new workbook based on tab name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create some VBA code to do the following:

1. A specific folder contains multiple excel files and each tab has the name of a (let's say) city.
2. An excel list defines to which country a city belongs. (column A = London, Paris, Boston, New-York and column B = U-K, France, U.S, U.S)
3. I would like a code looping through the folder and creating an additional file per country regrouping all the cities (there is only one tab per city but there are multiple files)

So far, nothing I tried seems to work.

Comment: Please show us the thing you've tried that has failed the least :).

Answer (score 0):

The question is extremly broad but this basic logic might help:

Use this post to work out how to loop through a directory:
[Specify Additional Directory to Loop Through Excel/VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303051/specify-additional-directory-to-loop-through-excel-vba/10303318#10303318)

This code template should give you enough to get started. Work with it, improve your question and we might be able to help you further.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySomeSheets()

    ' Loop through directory as in Question of this post
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim cityNameList() As Variant
    Dim cityName As Variant


    ' Pseudocode, next line is a dummy to make example code run
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' For Each wb In directory, as from post above
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            For Each cityName In cityNameList

                ' Could do this as a loop for each country or think a bit more and produce a smarter iteration with range lookup/2d array or somethnig to better match the shape of your data
                cityNameList = Range("A1:A10") ' List of cities are in this range
                If InStr(ws.Name, cityName) Then
                    ' Do stuff, i.e. save workbook with required name
                End If

            Next cityName
        Next ws
    ' Next wb




End Sub
```